# Python Count number of records within a given date range

Tags: python, mysql

We have a backend table that stores details of transaction including seconds since epoch. I am creating a UI where I collect from-to dates to display counts of transaction occurred in-between the dates.

Assuming that the date range is from 07/01/2012 - 07/30/2012, I am unable to establish a logic that will increment a counter for records that happened within the time period. I should hit the DB only once as hitting for each day will give poor performance.

I am stuck at a logic:

```
Convert 07/01/2012 & 07/30/2012 to seconds since epoch.
Get the records for start date - end date [as converted to seconds since epoch] 
   For each record get the month / date 
     -- now how will we add counters for each date in between 07/01/2012 - 07/30/2012
```

Comment: Assign each date range a key in a dictionary, +1 to the value each time you find an item within that range?

Comment: @cdarke: you can do it in MySQL altogether..

Comment: @Prakash: sorry, I don't know (looks like you have the answer anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has the function [`FROM_UNIXTIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) which will convert your seconds since epoch into datetime and you can then extract the `DATE` part of it (`YYYY-MM-DD` format) and group according to it.

```
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp_column)), COUNT(*)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp_column))
```

This will return something like

```
2012-07-01  2
2012-07-03  4
…
```

(no entries for days without transactions)

Comment: Thanks a lot but one question - if in case for a date there are no records I should get something like : 2012-07-04  0 also. Thanks its a great help

Comment: Perfect :-) You already had my upvote, I saw no sense in scooping you on that small issue alone..

Comment: @Prakash: That'll complicate things enormously. Use python logic for that part (parse the whole thing into a dictionary, for example, then handle missing dates via `get(date, 0)`).

Comment: @Prakash - you will need some datetime logic there (which knows there is 2012-02-29 but no 2012-02-30, and so on). You can build it in Python with `dateutil.rrule`, which is simpler than doing the same thing in MySQL.

Comment: @eumiro: A simple `date += timedelta(days=1)` loop should suffice should it not?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - yes, something like `[startDate + timedelta(days=i) for i in xrange((endDate - startDate).days + 1)]`

Comment: You can do this all on the server, even if you need data for days that aren't in the table. Just join with an auxiliary calendar table (google "calendar table" if you're unfamiliar with the concept).